# How to use GtkAda in command-line?

Tags: windows, gtk, mingw, gtk3, ada

I try to compile a very simple GtkAda application in command-line, on Windows. Here is the app code:

```
`WITH Gtk.Main ;       USE Gtk.Main ; 
WITH Gtk.Window ;     USE Gtk.Window ; 
PROCEDURE Test01 IS
   win : Gtk_window ;
BEGIN
   Init ; 
   Gtk_New(Win) ;
   Win.show_all ; 
   Main ; 
END Test01 ;`
```

Compiling with

`gcc -c test01.adb -IC:\<<path_to_GtkAda\include\gtkada>>`,
I obtain test.ali and test01.o as expected.

But **how to link the libs** please?

```
gcc test.o -LC:\<<path_to_GtkAda>>\lib
```

gives:

```
`Test01.o:Test01.adb:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `gtk__main__init'
Test01.o:Test01.adb:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `gtk__window__gtk_new'
Test01.o:Test01.adb:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `__gnat_rcheck_CE_Access_Check'
Test01.o:Test01.adb:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `gtk__main__main'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Test01.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_f
rame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

PATH already contains `<<path_to_GtkAda>>/bin`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution usually is to use GNAT's project files as described in the documentation installed with the compiler, typically in the “*doc*” or "*doc*/*gprbuild*” subdirectory.

A simple example project file named “*SO.gpr*” might look like this:

```
with "gtkada";
project SO is

 for Source_Dirs use (".");

end SO;
```

Note the part that says `with "gtkada";`. It means that the toolchain then will inject all switches that are necessary to make an Ada/GTK program. 
Then, if you invoke the GNAT toolchain like this:

```
$ gnatmake -PSO test01.adb
```

the Ada make program will call, in sequence, `gcc`, `gnatbind`, and `gnatlink`. For each, the necessary arguments to the commands will be supplied automatically.
(Depending on which edition of GNAT you are using, you may also use `gprbuild`.)

So, for example on a Debian/GNU system with `libgtkada2.24.4-dev` installed, I see this:

> ```
> $ gnatmake -Pso test01.adb
> gcc-4.9 -c -I- -gnatA /home/bauhaus/News/SO/test01.adb
> gnatbind -shared -x /home/bauhaus/News/SO/test01.ali
> gnatlink /home/bauhaus/News/SO/test01.ali -shared-libgcc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lgtkada -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lX11 -lm -o /home/bauhaus/News/SO/test01
> $
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :-) +1  I will try this!